# jQuery Trigger Event Inline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, jquery-trigger

I have created a couple of custom events, "check" and "uncheck".  I can easily use jQuery to implement these like this:

```
$("input:checkbox,input:radio").on("click",function(){
  if (j$(this).is(":checked")) {
    j$(this).trigger({
      type: "check"
    });
  } else {
    j$(this).trigger({
      type: "uncheck"
    });
  }
});
```

How can I allow for inline binding of this event?

`<input type="checkbox" oncheck="fee('arg1','arg2')" onuncheck="fi('arg1','arg2')" />`

**Edit**

My start to implement this could be somewhere along the lines of this:

```
$("[oncheck]").each(function(){
  $(this).on("check",function(){
    eval($(this).attr("oncheck"));
  });
});
$("[onuncheck]").each(function(){
  $(this).on("uncheck",function(){
    eval($(this).attr("onuncheck"));
  });
});
```

However, although I know it would work, I'm very opposed to using `eval` for this.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? HTML has a limited set of attributes for hooking events anyway: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp

Comment: Edited question.  Basically I've created these custom events which work when I use `$(something).on("check")` and `$(something).on("uncheck")`, but I need to be able to tie my custom event to the corresponding inline attribute.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the approach. I'm guessing that you need to store extra data in the checkbox (like its price or something). If so, you could use [data attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) and have your onclick event look there for instructions.

Comment: I guess I'm sticking with eval.  Kinda makes sense I guess.